# Kibana : count on many fields

Tags: elasticsearch, count, logstash, kibana

Is it possible to query for a count of many fields using Kibana? I am using elastic search as my backend to Kibana and parsing logs with logstash.

with SQL we can do: select count(*) from aTable group by filed_1, field_2, field_3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That SQL would give you a count of the combination of field_1, field_2, and field_3.  Note that it wouldn't actually *show* you the combinations.

You can create something similar in kibana with the Data Table visualization.  Add a bucket for field_1, then subbuckets for field_2 and field_3.

This one will show you the combinations.  Hopefully that's close enough.